# Incorrect PE size and section when compiling Win32 EXE with GCC

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc, portable-executable

One of the simplest C programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Function main.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is compiled with GCC (`gcc sample.c -o sample.exe`) I am using GCC as the compiler for Windows. The problem is the actual binary's header size and some empty data that gcc leaves behind. The following image is the data of an EXE compiled with GCC

[image: PE information when compiled with GCC]

This picture is the header data of an EXE compiled with MSVC

[image: This is the output of an EXE compiled with MSVC]

As the two images show, GCC sets the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::SizeOfImage` value incorrectly, whereas MSVC sets it correctly. In addition, the section header for the section `.bss` reports `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER::SizeOfRawData` to be `0`. How do I make sure the correct `SizeOfImage` value is set in the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` with GCC? Is there a way to remove the `.bss` section with GCC aswell?

Comment: every section have 2 different size - `SizeOfRawData` (size on disk) and `VirtualSize` (size in memory). well known example *.bss* section - uninitialized data here. no sense take size on disk for it. so `SizeOfRawData == 0`, but `VirtualSize != 0`. *size of the actual image is incorrect* - no, this again - **size in memory** which not equal size on disk

Comment: Yes I understand that this is the size in memory. If you look at EXE compiled by MSVC, the values are correct. @RbMm

Comment: which **concrete** values is incorrect ? why it is incorrect ?

Comment: If you want us to compare two things please show us the 2 things.  Apso please say what the expected values are.

Comment: Let me update my question

Comment: *like .bss, as it's size is 0* - **what concrete** size ? `SizeOfRawData` or `VirtualSize` ? if (i guess) it `SizeOfRawData` - this is ok and must be. *size of the actual image is incorrect* - **what** size ? `SizeOfImage` form `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` ? what ? how you decide that value is incorrect ? if size is incorrect - pe will be not load and run. if it run - size correct

Comment: What tool created that output? You seem to be trusting it on blind faith.

Comment: Which version of GCC and is this actually causing a problem?

Comment: @RbMm Yes, `SizeOfRawData` is 0. If it's `0` it's better to remove the section, right? Also the size is `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::SizeOfImage.`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings PE Viewer from the ProcessHacker project created this tool. I have been using this tool extensively for a long time and I don't believe there's a problem with the tool.

Comment: Even though it's saying your valid program that runs has an "invalid size"? You really should not make assumptions, especially when you've encountered something you're questioning.

Comment: @ArushAgarampur - no, not right. i already explain this. where will be located your data in memory if you remove section ?! and no sense compare exe created by 2 different tolls. why you decide that gcc not correct ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles My GCC version is `8.1.0 MinGW-W64` The reason I need the value to be correct is because my program references the `SizeOfImage` value from the PE header often and it depends on it being correct.

Comment: *Is there a way to remove the .bss section with GCC aswell?* - yes, possible. but after this exe will crash. better just remove all exe

Comment: again - **why** you decide that *SizeOfImage* is incorrect ? how you calc correct size ?

Comment: @RbMm Ok, I understand you explanation for the `.bss` section. I'm confused - is `SizeOfImage` disk size or mapped memory size?

Comment: but i already say - this is mapped memory size. not size on disk

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.